# Importing transistor spice model to LTSpice not working

Tags: ltspice

Using LTSpice XVII.  I want to import the Diodes Incorporated ZXTP19020DG model.  The SPICE model from their web site is:

```
*DIODES_INC_SPICE_MODEL ZXTP19020DG
*SIMULATOR=SIMETRIX
*ORIGIN=DZSL_DPG
*DATE=7/01/2013
*VERSION=1

.MODEL ZXTP19020DG PNP IS=8.5E-13 NF=1 BF=530 VAF=25.8 ISE=1.2E-13
+ IKF=3.8 NE=1.48 BR=130 VAR=5.15 ISC=0.8E-13 NC=1.23 RC=0.0045 RB=0.15
+ RE=0.009 QUASIMOD=1 RCO=0.27 GAMMA=2E-10 CJC=112E-12 MJC=0.4 VJC=0.6
+ CJE=345E-12 MJE=0.53 VJE=0.95 TF=0.59E-9 TR=4.2E-9 TRC1=.003 TRB1=.003
+ TRE1=.003 XTB=1.4
```

I copy-n-paste the `.MODEL` stanza into the `standard.bjt` file. I then open LTSpice and create a new schematic.  I add a PNP transistor, right-click to Pick New Transistor, but the ZXTP19020DG does not show up on the list.

It may seem like I need to tell LTSpice to reload the components — if I erase the 2N2222 and 2N2907 (the first two entries in the original `standard.bjt` file), the 2N2907 still shows up on the Pick New Transistor dialog (for a PNP transistor).  In all cases, I close and re-open LTSpice after any changes to `standard.bjt`. I also checked that there is only one `standard.bjt` file on the whole C: drive (under `C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp`).

This is what the beginning of the `standard.bjt` file looks like (I also added the NPN version, ZXTN19020DG, just in case):

```
* Copyright © 2000 Linear Technology Corporation.   All rights reserved.
*
*
.model ZXTN19020DG NPN IS=9E-13 NF=1 BF=530 IKF=6 VAF=105 ISE=8E-14
+ NE=1.4 NR=1  BR=174 IKR=1 VAR=12.8 ISC=4E-13 NC=1.37 RB=0.17 RE=0.0055
+ RC=0.0035 CJC=89E-12 MJC=0.34 VJC=0.51 CJE=365E-12 MJE=0.39 VJE=0.8
+ TF=9E-10 TR=0.55E-8 XTB=1.4 TRC1=.005 TRB1=.005 TRE1=.005 QUASIMOD=1
+ RCO=0.15 GAMMA=0.3E-9

.model ZXTP19020DG PNP IS=8.5E-13 NF=1 BF=530 VAF=25.8 ISE=1.2E-13
+ IKF=3.8 NE=1.48 BR=130 VAR=5.15 ISC=0.8E-13 NC=1.23 RC=0.0045 RB=0.15
+ RE=0.009 QUASIMOD=1 RCO=0.27 GAMMA=2E-10 CJC=112E-12 MJC=0.4 VJC=0.6
+ CJE=345E-12 MJE=0.53 VJE=0.95 TF=0.59E-9 TR=4.2E-9 TRC1=.003 TRB1=.003
+ TRE1=.003 XTB=1.4

.model 2N2222 NPN(IS=1E-14 VAF=100
+   BF=200 IKF=0.3 XTB=1.5 BR=3
+   CJC=8E-12 CJE=25E-12 TR=100E-9 TF=400E-12
+   ITF=1 VTF=2 XTF=3 RB=10 RC=.3 RE=.2 Vceo=30 Icrating=800m  mfg=NXP)

.model 2N2907 PNP(IS=1E-14 VAF=120
+   BF=250 IKF=0.3 XTB=1.5 BR=3
+   CJC=8E-12 CJE=30E-12 TR=100E-9 TF=400E-12
+   ITF=1 VTF=2 XTF=3 RB=10 RC=.3 RE=.2 Vceo=40 Icrating=600m mfg=NXP)

etc.
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Add a parenthesis after PNP or NPN .model ZXTN19020DG NPN (IS=9E-13 NF=1 BF=530 IKF=6 VAF=105 ISE=8E-14
+ NE=1.4 NR=1  BR=174 IKR=1 VAR=12.8 ISC=4E-13 NC=1.37 RB=0.17 RE=0.0055
+ RC=0.0035 CJC=89E-12 MJC=0.34 VJC=0.51 CJE=365E-12 MJE=0.39 VJE=0.8
+ TF=9E-10 TR=0.55E-8 XTB=1.4 TRC1=.005 TRB1=.005 TRE1=.005 QUASIMOD=1
+ RCO=0.15 GAMMA=0.3E-9) This work for me.

Comment: Didn't work.  I first added it without space between the NPN/PNP and the parenthesis as in the other entries in the file, then added a space as in your comment. Neither one works.  I also noticed that the list has columns for manufacturer, Vceo, and Ic --- so, I added made-up values of Vceo and Icrating as well as a mfg parameter at the end;  still doesn't not work.

Comment: An "extra-fishy" detail:  I edit the `standard.bjt` file and **remove** the entries 2N2222, 2N2907, 2N3904, and 2N3906.  Save the file, close LTSpice, re-launch LTSpice, add a PNP transistor, right-click on it, and the "Pick New Transistor" dialog does show 2N2907 and 2N3906.  Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351035/how-can-i-change-the-standard-jft-bjt-dio-cap-files-in-lt-spice-xvii

Comment: @G36 -- BINGO!  The file was the one under "My Documents"  :-\  Turns out that on Wine, the "My Documents" folder is a symbolic link to the Unix user's home directory, but the search function in the file browser does not follow symlinks;  that's why I searched for standard.bjt under the C: drive and it only showed one, the one under `c:\Program Files` ...  Oh well, mystery solved, it is working now!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add a + to indicate a line extension, its 1 line per model. It should look like the others. Here is an example:

```
.model RFNL5BM6S D(Is=778.9p N=1.419 Rs=25.53m Ikf=81.74m Eg=1.05 Cjo=93p M=513.2m Vj=714.8m Isr=358.2p Nr=3 Bv=600 tt=88.29n Tikf=18m Trs1=700u Iave=5 Vpk=600 mfg=Rohm type=FastRecovery)
```

Second thing, check your directory. The new LT spice places a folder in

```
 User\Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.dio
```

this is the one that needs to be edited.